# Backup a removable device with Time Machine

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

I want to backup my mac and a removable device to a AFP volume.
I know how to backup my mac, but how about the mounted volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will also be backed up unless you specifically exclude them in the Time Machine preference pane. They may be excluded by default, so you'd just need to un-exclude them.

Comment: Are you sure? when i get the size of the backup i get only the size of my mac, not the removable device + my mac

Comment: Confirmed it dont backups my volume, an i dont have exclusions

Comment: I assume these are USB/firewire disks? I don't think TM handles network storage.

Comment: It's an usb disk with a truecrypt volume inside.